# Unload a .swf upon exit of a frame

Tags: actionscript-3, function, parent-child, flash-cs5

I realise that this question has been asked before and I have tried all the majority of the solutions and to no avail. In my flash file I have an external .swf loading in a the goGallery frame but now when I go to a different frame that .swf file is still in the background.

Below is the code, if you could also tell me where to place the new code, that would be great as I've tried putting the solutions in and around it multiple times.

```
stop();

function listenerFunction (Event):void{
}


function goHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("Home");
}
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome);

function goAbout (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("About");
}
about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goAbout);

function goHistory (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("History");
}
history_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHistory);

function goEducation (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Education");
}
education_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goEducation);

function goInterests (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Interests");
}
interests_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goInterests);

function goGoals (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Goals");
}
goals_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goGoals);

function goPuzzle (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Puzzle");
}
puzzle_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPuzzle);

function goSound (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Sound");
}
sound_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goSound);

function goGallery (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Gallery");
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                    
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("gallery.swf"); 
myLoader.load(url);                                     
addChild(myLoader);

myLoader.x = 380;                                         
myLoader.y = 270;

myLoader.scaleX = 0.45; 
myLoader.scaleY = 0.45; 

}

gallery_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goGallery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to `myLoader` and remove it when you don't want it on the stage.

```
var galleryLoader:Loader = new Loader();

function goGallery (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("Gallery");

    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("gallery.swf"); 
    galleryLoader.load(url);                                     
    addChild(galleryLoader);
}
```

Inside the other functions remove the galleryLoader :

```
function goHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
    removeGallery();
    gotoAndStop("Home");
}

function removeGallery():void
{
    if(galleryLoader.parent)
       galleryLoader.parent.removeChild(galleryLoader);
}
```